# How do I retrieve a single row from a table using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a table and stored values in it. The table has a column 'ID' which is unique.

Now I’ve created a form where there is a button marked *Retrieve*. When I enter the ID and click the *Retrieve* button, I want to view the data corresponding to this ID.

How do I do this using PHP and MYSQL?

I’ve got some code below, but it isn‘t working. No error message is being showed. But there is no problem with the db connection. Rest of the functions working except for 'RETRIEVE'.

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'DB';
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if(mysqli_connect_error()) 
{
die("couldn't connect" . $conn->connect_error());
}
echo ("connected successfully");
$id = $_POST['Id'];
$name = $_POST['Name'];
$blood = $_POST['BloodGroup'];


if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
        $insert = "Insert into ins(Id, name, BloodGroup) values ('$id','$name', '$blood')" ;
        if($conn->query($insert) === TRUE) {
        echo ("Input data entered successfully");
        } else {
        echo ("Input data failed to be entered" . $conn->error());
        }
        $conn->close();
} elseif(isset($_POST['update'])) {

        $update = "update ins set Name='".$name."', BloodGroup='".$blood."' where Id='".$id."'";
        mysql_query($update);
        if($conn->query($update) === TRUE) {
        echo ("Data updated successfully");
        } else {
        echo ("Data cant be updated" . $conn->error());
        }
        $conn->close();
} elseif(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        $id = $_POST['Id'];
        $delete = "delete from ins where Id='".$id."'";
        if($conn->query($delete) === TRUE) {
        echo ("Data deleted successfully");
        } else {
        echo ("Data cant be updated" . $conn->error());
        }
        $conn->close();
}
else {
$id = $_POST['Id'];
$retrieve = "SELECT * FROM ins WHERE Id = ".'$id'."";
$dis = $db->query($retrieve);
$row = $dis->fetch_assoc();
echo 'Details are: '.$row['id'];
}
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Although it's not what you're asking, your code is vulnerable to several SQL injection attacks, which can and *will* cause data loss and privacy problems for your users. Please find some information about the topic and don't put this code in production like that!

Comment: Yeah okay. thanks. Anyway I'm just checking how it works. This is not the final one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Change sql select clause into this:

```
"SELECT * FROM ins WHERE Id = " .$id. " LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$retrieve = "SELECT * FROM ins WHERE Id = ".$id." LIMIT 1";
```

The limit will work for you

Answer (score 0):

In the SQL statement ($retrieve), the single quotes are killing it for you. Try either of the following:

1. Remove the single quotes around `$id` and keep the rest of the statement the same
2. Change `'$id'` to `"'{$id}'"` (if you're keen on getting the single quotes around the `$id` value - just in case `$id` is a text value and not a number)

Comment: The 'id' value is just a number. Let me try it.

Comment: 1. Notice: Undefined variable: db in ......   2. Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in ....

Comment: I notice that the name column in your table isn't following your regular camel case convention with Id and BloodGroup. Maybe this is causing the error?

Comment: Just saw your comment.

Comment: Well, that clarifies it doesn't it? You need to initialize the $db variable. Instantiate the $db variable and hopefully that'll go away

Answer (score 0):

Try this
$retrieve = "SELECT * FROM ins WHERE Id = ".$id;
$dis = $db->query($retrieve);
$row = $dis->fetch_row();